# As Stack Exchange does

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> You may call me fake,
>
> but with great power I *make*,
>
> and I keep you awake.
>
> From a Stack Exchange site, my name I use.
>
> Be careful with your commands, don't abuse!

What am I?

Comment: I feel like the existing answers aren't accounting for the italics in _make_. Personally, my mind jumped to GNU make, but I'm having trouble going anywhere with it

Comment: Only thing I can think of is [worldbuilding.se] but I can't figure out how that keeps you awake.

Comment: I've added a clue to hopefully narrow down the riddle from the answers given below. I've put in my vote for reopening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you:

> Sudo?

You may call me fake:

> Sudo sounds the same as *pseudo*

but with great power I make:

> e.g. sudo make install, making with superuser privileges.

and I keep you awake:

> As root, you can disable the screen lock/saver and power down, keeping the computer awake.

From a Stack Exchange site, my name I use:

> Superuser

Be careful with your commands, don't abuse!

> Don't use sudo to force things [a regular user shouldn't have permissions for](https://xkcd.com/838/).

And the title "As stack exchange does":

> A bit of a stretch, maybe as people do on stack overflow when they copy code they don't understand and execute it.

Comment: looks like someone else had the same idea as me

Comment: @gl_prout looks like yours is closer though :)

Comment: you found out about the clues tho

Comment: You got all of the clues except awake (hint: related to first line). Also the title is just a copy of the stack exchange reference which you got.

Answer (score 7):

I want to say this is:

> Reputation points.

You may call me fake

> People call it Meaningless/Fake Internet Points.

but with great power I make

> Higher reputation gives you higher privileges, i.e. more power in a site.

and I keep you awake

> Higher rep also means you are/were a regular contributor to a site and that's one way to be kept awake(?)

TITLE:

> Stack Exchange awards us reputation.

Comment: @noedne predicted this, but incorrect. When I say make, this answer doesn't make anything. Also keeping awake is a stretch.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is

> News

You may call me fake

> By now, the term 'fake news' is pretty common.

but with great power I make

> News has great power over people, influencing society in many ways.
>  News is also made by people with great power, and can make positions of great power i.e. Donald Trump's presidential campaign was made partially by the news media.

and I keep you awake

> News has become intrusive in our lives, with current events being a click away

Title

> Not too sure about this, but my guess is that this has something to do with Stack Exchange making the news.

Comment: Sorry nope. I mean make and awake more literally. And the title doesn't fit.

Answer (score 6):

I am:

> Bitcoin

You may call me fake,

> Many people consider Bitcoin to be a fake currency.

but with great power I make,

> It takes a lot of power to mine Bitcoin.

and I keep you awake.

> The volatility of Bitcoin is certainly enough to "keep you up at night".

Title: As Stack Exchange does:

> Well, there's this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Possibility **#1**:

> Email

You may call me fake,

> Fake email, which is not authentic

but with great power I make,

> it can be used as a formal communication

and I keep you awake.

> by waiting for them, reading and writing them

Title:

> user needs to have one

Possibility **#2**:

> Community

You may call me fake,

> Could be considered fake, since it is online, and users don't really need each other

but with great power I make,

> well, moderators have power, and highly involved members can even put that in their CVs.

and I keep you awake.

> by being involved in questions, answers and chat.

Title:

> Stack Exchange is all about community!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say

> an orgasm

It may be referred to as fake...can you really tell? :)

With great power I make and I keep you awake.... Well we would hope this is true. You certainly wouldn't want to be asleep at the time...

Comment: does StackExchange offer a "premium" service now?

Comment: @L_Church Well, there's [this failed beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sexuality).

Comment: Should have been upgraded to a master beta...

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> AI/Artificial intelligence

You may call me fake,

> It is "Artificial"

but with great power I make,

> It learns things on its own and can make things on its own.

and I keep you awake.

> It is pretty scary to think robots might rule the world someday... and it might keep you up.

Also,

> [AI site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> light?

You may call me fake,

> Some light is *artificial* (i.e. light bulbs).

but with great power I make,

> We generate a lot of electricity to produce light.

and I keep you awake.

> Light keeps us awake at night, when we should be sleeping.

As Stack Exchange does

> It *enlightens* us by answering our questions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Money?

"You may call me fake"

> Money doesn't have any real value

"But with great power I make"

> Money drives people to produce

"I keep you awake"

> Money can cause sleepless nights.

And the site.

> https://money.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try this

> User

You may call me fake

> Fake user accounts on the internet

But with great power I make

> su

And I keep you awake

> I have no clue in which way though

From a Stack Exchange site, my name I use

> superuser ?

Be careful with your commands, don't abuse

> Beware the # rm -rf /*

Awaiting feedback

Comment: You are very close... you just need to get fake and awake

Comment: if I got close enough, I guess it's okay for me, it's the first time I can kinda answer a puzzle here :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Coffee?

As stack exchange does

> Programmers have a stereotype of drinking a lot of coffee, and SE has many users who are programmers.

You may call me fake,

> A lot of people think coffee doesn't really affect them and is more of a placebo

but with great power I make,

> But you can make a very potent pot of coffee

and I keep you awake.

> And it will keep you awake if you drink it

Comment: Clever but I don't think anyone calls your answer fake.

Comment: There are several types of "fake coffee"

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at this. I think you are

> Software Engineering

You may call me fake,

> It does not produce tangible goods, and so many consider it not-real, which is a synonym for "fake"

but with great power I make,

> It is used to make software, and the tool to convert code into executable applications is often *make*, and the compilation process can involve a significant amount of computing power.

and I keep you awake.

> Coders are notorious for being night owls. Also, the symbol for the Stack Exchange site for Software Engineering is a coffee cup

From a Stack Exchange site, my name I use.

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Be careful with your commands, don't abuse!

> Bugs in code can be very dangerous, and code is about telling a computer what to do (a command)

As Stack Exchange Does

> Stack Exchange is a major destination for programmers, but also produces its own [API](https://stackapps.com/) and [Open Source code](https://github.com/StackExchange), making Software Engineering a thing that Stack Exchange does both as an entity and as a community.

Answer (score -1):

Are you

> Love

"You may call me fake"

> Love is often questioned

"But with great power I make"

> Babies, say no more...

"I keep you awake"

> Thinking about someone, or yet again, babies, say no more...

The Title:

> Stack exchange loving all its users seems a bit corny, this bit doesn't fit so well